# сдвиг изображения вправо

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

нужно двинуть 2 картинки к правому краю, пробовал через float, но не помогает. внешние отступы сделаны, нужно просто передвинуть элементы. теоретически можно сделать через margin-left: xx; но мне кажется, что это будет неправильно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитай про display: flex

https://tpverstak.ru/flex-cheatsheet/

Если кратко, тебе родительскому тэгу нужно задать свойства:

```css
.parent {
//Родительский тэг
display: flex;
justify-content: space-between;
}
```